# Create hash in ruby instantly

Tags: ruby, hash

I was searching on the internet for some easy interpretation of hashes in ruby but I haven`t found (let me know if you found). Thing is I am looking for a nice and efficient way to create hash values on the go. Here is my current example:

```
home = {}
home['rooms'] = {}
home['rooms']['kitchen'] = 'this is kitchen'
home['rooms']['hall'] = 'welcome in hall'
```

But this is really long interpretation. I am searching something similar in ruby to this:

```
home = {}
home['rooms']['kitchen'] = 'this is kitchen'
home['rooms']['kitchen']['some_parameter']['some_parameter2'] = 'random text'
```

I don`t want to define hash on the each step.

```
home['rooms'] = {}
home['rooms']['kitchen'] = {}
home['rooms']['kitchen']['some_parameter'] = {}
```

I hope it was clear what is my intent, if not I will answer in comments. During my code I would like to define new hashes. I don`t know the structure before, so idea is when I create new var[p1][p2][p3] it will be automatically created as hash and it it will not produce an error.

The thing is, those hashes keys can be created dynamically, from variable.

Comment: Hi Markus. @rdalpra is right that you can define it all as a single declaration, and you should. I'm just wondering why you're defining it in this way, is the goal something where you're getting the end values from something else?

Comment: Hi @AJFaraday, the thing is, those hashes keys can be created dynamically, from variable. So therefore structure before is not solution for me.

Comment: That's why I'm asking what you're actually trying to achieve here. It feels like you're asking how to do something which isn't quite what you need to do.

Comment: hi @AJFaraday, asking questions is not my strong side, but I am working on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a hash which uses another hash as its default value:

```
home = Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }

home['rooms']['kitchen'] = 'this is kitchen'
home['rooms']['hall'] = 'welcome in hall'

home
#=> {"rooms"=>{"kitchen"=>"this is kitchen", "hall"=>"welcome in hall"}}
```

Passing [`default_proc`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Hash.html#method-i-default_proc) on to the inner hash ensures that you can nest it indefinitely:

```
home['foo']['bar']['baz'] = 'qux'

home
#=> {"rooms"=>{"kitchen"=>"this is kitchen", "hall"=>"welcome in hall"},
#    "foo"=>{"bar"=>{"baz"=>"qux"}}}
```

Comment: very cool answer .. for easy reuse, and perhaps efficiency, you can store that as a proc assigned to a constant 

```HASH_CTOR = lambda { Hash.new { |h, k| h[k] = Hash.new(&h.default_proc) }} }

home = HASH_CTOR.call
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the entire hash (if you know the keys you want) when you instantiate the first one.

Something like this:

```rb
home = { 
  rooms: {  
    kitchen: '',
    hall: ''
  } 
}

home[:rooms][:kitchen] = 'this is kitchen'
home[:rooms][:hall] = 'welcome in hall'
```

If you already have the values:

```rb
home = { 
  rooms: {  
    kitchen: 'this is kitchen',
    hall: 'welcome in hall'
  } 
}
```

If you could provide a use case example, that would probably enable more precise answers.

EDIT:
If you want to access your keys with either `String` or `Symbol`:

```rb
home = { 
  rooms: {  
    kitchen: 'this is kitchen',
    hall: 'welcome in hall'
  } 
}.with_indifferent_access
```